# Error when trying to insert a comment on a blog post php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to insert comments on a blog post and I keep getting an error message. I don't know if the database is set correctly, or if i'm missing some syntax error. I have a form page and a handle page. This is the form:

```
<h1><center> Add comment form</center></h1>
<form action="hc.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<h3>Post comment.</h3> <br>
<textarea name="comment"cols="50"rows="10"id="comment" >

</textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="comid" value="'.$comid .'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="blogid" value="'.$blogid .'"/>

<input type="submit"value="Submit"name="submit" />
<input type="reset"value="Clear">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

My handle page is as following:

```
  <?php
include ('./includes/mysqli_connect.php');

$blogid = $_SESSION['blogid'];

$comment = $_SESSION['comment'];
$comdate = $_SESSION['comdate'];
$comid = $_SESSION['comid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

//if (isset($_GET['blogid']) && isset($_GET['userid']) && isset($_GET['comment'])){
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(comid, blogid, userid, comment, comdate) VALUES ('$comid', '$blogid','$userid','$comment','$comdate')";
$result= @mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

$comid=NULL;
$blogid=NULL;
$userid=NULL;

if ($results) {
echo "Thank you  your information has been submitted.";
} else {
    echo "There was an error! " . mysqli_error($dbc);
}
?>
```

I am new at php and appreciate the  help.

The error message is:

> There was an error! Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`codecrew_users`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT
>   `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`blogid`) REFERENCES `blog` (`blogid`))

Comment: What is error and at which line it occuring?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), PHP variables are case sensitive. `$_SESSION` is completely different than `$_session`, using `@` to supress errors is the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you", and `$result` is NOT the same as `$results`.

Comment: where yours `$comid` and `$userid` variables are set? If you are getting from session, you should use `$_SESSION['index']` **and make sure you are setting them somewhere in your code**

Comment: the error that im getting is :

Comment: There was an error! Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`codecrew_users`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`blogid`) REFERENCES `blog` (`blogid`))

Comment: How's you get $comid and $userid?

Comment: I fixed a few things but still no compile ;(

Comment: You don't want those single quotes around any data that is going into an integer column. And as others have pointed out, you (1) have a lot of typos and (2) are extremely vulnerable to SQL injection. Fix that or you will get hacked, guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(comid, blogid, userid, comment, comdate) VALUES ('$comid', '$blogid','$userid','$comment','$comdate')";
```

So... Your table `comments` has some field on it that requires a foreign key.

I'm not sure which value is causing the error however one of your values does not match an id in another table.

So one of these has an invalid value:

```
'$comid', '$blogid','$userid','$comment','$comdate'
```